# How to initialize specific class object inside a class?

Tags: python, oop

For example I have a class Number with predefined values 1, 2, 3.

```
class Number:
  one = Number(1)
  two = Number(2)
  three = Number(3)

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.value = val
```

But I get NameError: Number is not defined. How should I deal with this problem or what is the right way to do this?

Comment: What use case are you trying to cater?

Comment: @sameerasy I have a Double class actually and I need to define special values such as Infinity.

Comment: @HenryDobert try to use class variable with infinity value say (-1 or something else). You can not create an object of the same class within that class definition.

Comment: @HenryDobert IIUC `Number.one = Number(1)` after the class definition will have the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Number is not defined.

Is this what you want to do?

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

class Number:
  one = Num(1)
  two = Num(2)
  three = Num(3)

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.value = val
```

Comment: No, that only gives us one redundant class.

Comment: Fair enough, but it resolves your Problem. You simply cannot recursively intantiate a class within itself.